# Tools for Linux 2.6.39 Compilation

Tags: linux-kernel

I have started working on linux for about 6 months or so and now I
wanted to compile Linux version 2.6.39. Here are my questions for
the upgrade :

a. How will I get the GCC, Make, BinUtil and other tool dependency
of linux with their versions.

b. After compiling the tools how to make toolchain for linux
compilation.

I have searched various websites for this. I got information in bits and pieces and for specific linux versions. Is their a site or something where I can get all the information about the upcoming linux upgrades with the details.

My Current Linux machine details are :
Distro : CentOS 4.8
Linux version : 2.6.9
Gcc Version : 3.4.6
Binutils : 2.15.92
Make : 3.80

-Tommy

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options, depending on that type of kernel you want to build:

1. If you want a kernel for your machine (or a similar one), you can use the GCC that you already have from your distro.
2. If you want a kernel for another architecture (like ARM, MIPS, etc) you NEED a **cross-compiler**. You can build a cross-compiler (a whole toolchain, actually) using something like [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/).

With crosstool-ng you can also build yourself a toolchain for the first case. This tool take care of downloading the tarballs with the sources for GCC, Binutils, glibc, etc.

If you just want to upgrade the kernel on your machine, regardless of the version, the steps are mostly the same:

1. Get the source with
      `wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.0/linux-3.2.9.tar.bz2` or something similar
2. extract them with `tar xjvf linux-*.tar.bz2` and then exter that folder
3. `make oldconfig` or `make menuconfig` or even better `make localmodconfig`
4. `make`
5. `make install` as root

Comment: Thanks for the links. I have tried option 1 and my machine is up.